# Does "Partner Super User" allows user create cases where a contact will be some other user/contact?

Tags: community, partner-communities, partner

According to https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=000383801&type=1
external users with Portal super user access can create cases for contacts other than themselves.
They can also edit the case and as a result of this editing a contact on the case will not be automatically set back to their own contact.

I wonder if Partner Super User has the same power over the contact field on a case?
I have found this https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.networks_partner_super_user_access.htm&type=5 , but it does not answer my question.